# Unity CIL Linker presents a log4net assembly error when building for Android

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, build, build-error

I'm unsure of what's causing the following errors when building for Android in Unity.

## Android build error

```cs
Building C:\Users\LIMEFRIENDS\Documents\GitHub\21cube\Library\Bee\artifacts\unitylinker_xy1a.traceevents failed with output:
C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2021.3.14f1\Editor\Data\il2cpp\build\deploy\UnityLinker.exe --search-directory=C:/Users/LIMEFRIENDS/Documents/GitHub/21cube/Temp/StagingArea/Data/Managed --out=Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/ManagedStripped --include-link-xml=C:/Users/LIMEFRIENDS/Documents/GitHub/21cube/Temp/StagingArea/Data/Managed\TypesInScenes.xml --include-link-xml=C:/Users/LIMEFRIENDS/Documents/GitHub/21cube/Temp/StagingArea/Data/Managed\SerializedTypes.xml --include-link-xml=C:\Users\LIMEFRIENDS\Documents\GitHub\21cube\Assets\FacebookSDK\link.xml --include-link-xml=C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2021.3.14f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/Tools/AndroidNativeLink.xml --include-directory=C:/Users/LIMEFRIENDS/Documents/GitHub/21cube/Temp/StagingArea/Data/Managed --profiler-report --profiler-output-file=C:/Users/LIMEFRIENDS/Documents/GitHub/21cube/Library/Bee/artifacts/unitylinker_xy1a.traceevents --dotnetprofile=unityaot-linux --dotnetruntime=Il2Cpp --platform=Android --use-editor-options --enable-engine-module-stripping --engine-modules-asset-file=C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2021.3.14f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/modules.asset --editor-data-file=C:/Users/LIMEFRIENDS/Documents/GitHub/21cube/Temp/StagingArea/Data/Managed/EditorToUnityLinkerData.json --include-unity-root-assembly=C:/Users/LIMEFRIENDS/Documents/GitHub/21cube/Temp/StagingArea/Data/Managed/Assembly-CSharp-firstpass.dll --include-unity-root-assembly=C:/Users/LIMEFRIENDS/Documents/GitHub/21cube/Temp/StagingArea/Data/Managed/Assembly-CSharp.dll --include-unity-root-assembly=C:/Users/LIMEFRIENDS/Documents/GitHub/21cube/Temp/StagingArea/Data/Managed/UnityEngine.UI.dll --include-unity-root-assembly=C:/Users/LIMEFRIENDS/Documents/GitHub/21cube/Temp/StagingArea/Data/Managed/Facebook.Unity.Settings.dll --print-command-line --enable-analytics
Fatal error in Unity CIL Linker
Mono.Linker.LinkerFatalErrorException: D:\JenkinsWorkspaces\trebuchet-stage-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Internal\Util\Logger.Log4net.cs(71,13): error IL1005: Amazon.Runtime.Internal.Util.InternalLog4netLogger.loadStatics(): Error processing method 'Amazon.Runtime.Internal.Util.InternalLog4netLogger.loadStatics()' in assembly 'AWSSDK.Core.dll'
 ---> System.InvalidOperationException: No action for the assembly log4net, Version=2.0.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=669e0ddf0bb1aa2a defined
   at Mono.Linker.AnnotationStore.GetAction(AssemblyDefinition assembly)
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.IsFullyPreserved(TypeDefinition type)
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkType(TypeReference reference, DependencyInfo reason, IMemberDefinition sourceLocationMember)
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkTypeVisibleToReflection(TypeReference reference, DependencyInfo reason, IMemberDefinition sourceLocationMember)
   at Mono.Linker.Dataflow.ReflectionMethodBodyScanner.<>c__DisplayClass20_4.<HandleCall>b__7()
   at Mono.Linker.Dataflow.ReflectionMethodBodyScanner.HandleCall(MethodBody callingMethodBody, MethodReference calledMethod, Instruction operation, ValueNodeList methodParams, ValueNode& methodReturnValue)
   at Mono.Linker.Dataflow.MethodBodyScanner.HandleCall(MethodBody callingMethodBody, Instruction operation, Stack`1 currentStack)
   at Mono.Linker.Dataflow.MethodBodyScanner.Scan(MethodBody methodBody)
   at Mono.Linker.Dataflow.ReflectionMethodBodyScanner.ScanAndProcessReturnValue(MethodBody methodBody)
   at Unity.Linker.Steps.UnityMarkStep.MarkReflectionLikeDependencies(MethodBody body, Boolean requiresReflectionMethodBodyScanner)
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkMethodBody(MethodBody body)
   at Unity.Linker.Steps.UnityMarkStep.MarkMethodBody(MethodBody body)
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessMethod(MethodDefinition method, DependencyInfo& reason)
   at Unity.Linker.Steps.UnityMarkStep.ProcessMethod(MethodDefinition method, DependencyInfo& reason)
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessQueue()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessQueue()
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessPrimaryQueue()
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.Process()
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.Process(LinkContext context)
   at Unity.Linker.Steps.UnityMarkStep.Process(LinkContext context)
   at Unity.Linker.UnityPipeline.ProcessStep(LinkContext context, IStep step)
   at Mono.Linker.Pipeline.Process(LinkContext context)
   at Unity.Linker.UnityDriver.UnityRun(Boolean noProfilerAllowed, ILogger customLogger)
   at Unity.Linker.UnityDriver.RunDriverWithoutErrorHandling(ILogger customLogger, Boolean noProfilerAllowed)
   at Unity.Linker.UnityDriver.RunDriver()
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)
```

## Build error number 1

```cs
C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2021.3.14f1\Editor\Data\il2cpp\build\deploy\il2cpp.exe --convert-to-cpp --data-folder=C:/Users/LIMEFRIENDS/Documents/GitHub/21cube/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/data --generatedcppdir=C:/Users/LIMEFRIENDS/Documents/GitHub/21cube/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp --additional-cpp=C:/Users/LIMEFRIENDS/Documents/GitHub/21cube/Library/PackageCache/com.unity.ads@3.7.5/Plugins/iOS/UnityAdsShowListener.h --additional-cpp=C:/Users/LIMEFRIENDS/Documents/GitHub/21cube/Library/PackageCache/com.unity.ads@3.7.5/Plugins/iOS/UnityAdsInitializationListener.h --additional-cpp=C:/Users/LIMEFRIENDS/Documents/GitHub/21cube/Library/PackageCache/com.unity.ads@3.7.5/Plugins/iOS/UnityAdsLoadListener.h --enable-analytics --emit-null-checks --enable-array-bounds-check --dotnetprofile=unityaot-linux --profiler-report --profiler-output-file=C:/Users/LIMEFRIENDS/Documents/GitHub/21cube/Library/Bee/artifacts/il2cpp_conv_yrc1.traceevents --print-command-line
Error: il2cpp.InvalidCommandLineArgumentsException: One or more assemblies must be specified using either --directory or --assembly
   at il2cpp.Conversion.ContextDataFactory.CreateConversionDataFromOptions(Il2CppCommandLineArguments il2CppCommandLineArguments)
   at il2cpp.Conversion.ConversionDriver.Run(Il2CppCommandLineArguments il2CppCommandLineArguments)
   at il2cpp.Program.DoRun(String[] args, RuntimePlatform platform, Il2CppCommandLineArguments il2CppCommandLineArguments, BuildingOptions buildingOptions, Boolean throwExceptions)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)
```

## Build error number 2

Check the path in Korean >> only English or num
Asset reimport all >> X

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I'm actually getting the same error ("il2cpp.InvalidCommandLineArgumentsException") so if you have been able to find a solution, please share.